# In Facebook, know the email when someone like my post?

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-like

Can I know the email when someone like's my post?
Example "A" like my post, can I now the A's email?
How can I know?

Thanks

Andiyono

Answer (score 1):

You cannot

(there is nothing to add, just some dummy text to satisfy SO answer length requirement)

Comment: There is no way to get the email when someone like my post?

Answer (score 1):

If the user's profile is in public, then you'll see the email in his/her profile information. But there's no way that you can see the email with just liking your post. Hope that helps.

Comment: Drayl, in apps facebook, we can get the email when someone allow my permissions... 

Is there any way to get the email when someone like my post??
such as make an page, or apps can post something?

Comment: @drayl: 1. could you give an example of such profile? 2. Programmatically email is available only after getting permission from user

Comment: What i actually meant was, if user "A"'s profile was not set in private or hidden you can view his information by visiting his/her account(that includes email). And about the app, I can't say if you can see his/her email because facebook is concern about user's privacy.

Comment: I don't concern see the email with visiting his/her account..
I just concern in API...
I can get the "A" 's email if "A" use my app...
but I can't post anything to others or to mine app so others can see my post...

All I want is when I post something, the one who like my post, will retrieve an email..

Is there any way?

Comment: No, there is no way. And most users won’t appreciate to get spammed by email, just because they liked something.

Comment: @CBroe
So, how can I do that?
I need to send email to whose liked my post...
Can I ?